# Host/Variable Not Declared Issue - But no declare/variables in script

Tags: oracle, variables

I am writing a basic insert script and at the beginning trying to delete what I am inserting later so the script can be run multiple times. Below is a small section of the code. I am getting errors like: "invalid host/bind variable name" and "Bind variable "SELECTIONS" not declared."

Ex:

```
SET DEFINE OFF

DELETE FROM SELECTIONS WHERE DATAFIELD IN ('ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd');

DELETE FROM SELECTION_LOCALE WHERE DATAFIELD IN ('ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd');

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO SELECTIONS (SELECTIONS_ID, DATAFIELD, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('CATCHANGE', 'ba', 'PI&D Library');

INSERT INTO SELECTIONS (SELECTIONS_ID, DATAFIELD, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('CATCHANGE', 'bb', 'Non-conformance');

INSERT INTO SELECTIONS (SELECTIONS_ID, DATAFIELD, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('CATCHANGE', 'bc', 'Alternative Route');

COMMIT;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It thinks PI&D is a bind variable. But normally SET DEFINE OFF fixes that. Try adding a semicolon after SET DEFINE OFF